# Log errors, and instead of displaying them, show a 500 Error Page in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to achieve the following for my site; first of all, this is for production mode only. My goal is to keep all errors hidden from the visitor, but log them and display a 500 Internal Server Error Page.

The part of hiding those errors is easy - the only thing is to turn off display_errors.

Right now, I am using a custom written function as error handler. It basically just sends a 500 Error Page, but neither that seems to work. Here is the function:

`function error_handler($errno, $errstr)
{
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
    die();
}`

Because of this, another error occurs - the errors don't get logged because I use die() at the end of this function.

Any idea how this might work?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function.

Comment: I wrote it in my post that I use a set_error_handler function to change the default error handler.

Comment: I'm sorry. Have you tried passing the error to the [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function?